# Установка другого дистрибутива Linux поверх существующего

Tags: загрузка, grub, linux

При установке нового дистрибутива рядом с существующим с той лишь разницей, что на другой раздел, grub автоматически добавит новый дистрибутив в список или же перезапишет себя заново с другим дистрибутивом?

Answer (score 1):

Перепишет, потом при апдейте найдёт все системы.